# NSMenuItem and bare esc key equiv

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, interface-builder

I'm trying to bind a bare esc key press to an NSMenuItem that toggles full screen (currently just a stub function). Manually selecting the menu item sends the desired IBAction. When I set the NSMenuItem's Key Equiv. in Interface Builder to an arbitrary bare key (eg. w) that key command sends the desired IBAction. When I set the Key Equiv. to command + esc, that key command sends the desired IBAction. But a bare esc key press is ignored.

I'm assuming the esc key is special-cased. Other applications (eg. Bannister's various emulators) are able to achieve this, any idea how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm no Objective-C veteran, so apologies if I'm misunderstanding the question. But have you tried moving up the responder chain and grabbing the keyDown event in NSWindow? Something like:

```
- (void)keyDown: (NSEvent *) event {
   if ([event keyCode] == 53) {
        NSLog(@"Esc. pressed");
     }
}
```

Of course, this solution will require that you subclass NSWindow.

Comment: Thanks Nial. I accepted this because it solves the general use problem. Unfortunately it only solves half of my specific problem (which I glossed over in my question). 

I'm using enterFullScreenMode:withOptions: to enter full screen mode which doesn't use my subclassed NSWindow. This solution allows me to enter but not exit full screen mode. Apple's GLFullScreen example code should get me the rest of the way. <http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/GLFullScreen/Introduction/Intro.html>

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, it should just be a case of implementing keyDown: within your NSView. Failing that, this may be of interest: http://www.mail-archive.com/cocoa-dev@lists.apple.com/msg03851.html

Comment: Implementing keyDown: in my NSOpenGLView subclass worked. This still all seems like arbitrary magic...Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The Escape key is tightly bound to the `cancelOperation` class of `NSResponder`.

Try to subclass your `NSWindow` and give it this method:

```
- (void)cancelOperation:(id)sender {
  if (![SomeController doSomeAction]) {
    [super cancelOperation:sender];
  }
}
```

Your window will then react to the Escape key and evoke `doSomeAction`. That would be the method your `NSMenuItem` would have liked to call, but it refused to do so :)

In the `doSomeAction` method you should return a Boolean that indicates whether the action did actually do something. If it did, good. If it did not (and returned `NO`), your `NSWindow` will pass on the Escape key event to the next responder in the chain.

I like this solution because it gives the user audio feedback about whether his key press actually did something. Because if your method didn't do anything, and no other repsonder did do anything, there will be some "beep" sound.

Note that in an `NSView` without an attached window, you might have to use `[self nextResponder]` instead of `super`.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/XHIGUserInput/XHIGUserInput.html
“… The Esc (Escape) key basically means “let me out of here.” It has specific meanings in certain contexts. The user can press Esc in the following situations: …”

Greetings